# Sci-fi/horror short story (anthology) with cannibalism and NSFW elements

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

When I was younger, perhaps 15-20 years ago, I read a science fiction short story anthology. The anthology might have been in Norwegian, but I'm not sure if the stories were translated, or if they (or some) were originally in Norwegian. I'm also not sure if the theme of the anthology was space horror, but it might have been.

I only remember one story, and that only vaguely. A man in a space suit was stranded in space, perhaps in the debris of a destroyed ship. Pretty sure he was in his space suit, in vacuum (at least zero g). He observed other people who performed cannibalism. In one memorable scene, someone (a woman?) bit off a person's penis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe I have actually found the answer on my own. Funny thing, I've been looking for this for ages without finding it, but once I decide to ask here I manage to ask Google the right things.

If I'm right, the story is actually in Norwegian. Funny that time makes you forget trivial details like what language a story is in.

The short story is likely "Siste reis" (1983) by Trond Buland, in the anthology by the same name. I've ordered the book to my local library to confirm.

Edit: All right, the library got the anthology *Siste reis*. The story I was after *was* in it, but it was *not* the short story by the same name. Instead, it was a story called "Barnerøveren" by one Salvator Quicksilver, which seems to be a pen name.

Comment: Wonderful! I suppose it's the usual English bias, but there's no entry for that guy on ISFDB.org as far as I can tell. Probably ought to remedy that...

Comment: He doesn't seem too prolific; it seems he wrote a bunch of short stories in the 80s and 90s (collected in two collections of his own, as well as published in several magazines and anthologies), and one novel published in 2005. All in Norwegian. I can think of many more prolific Norwegian sci-fi authors who should be added to ISFDB before him ;)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I got the book from the library now, and the short story I seeked was *not* "Siste reis" by Trond Buland, but it *was* contained in the anthology called *Siste reis* and which contained the Buland story! The story I was after was "Barnerøveren" by Salvator Quicksilver. That strange (non-Norwegian) name seems to be a pen name.

Comment: Ah. :) Just for the sake of reference, "sought", not "seeked". I... don't know why.

Comment: Oops. And my 5 minutes' edit window has passed. Oh well! Google tells me I'm not alone in that misconstruction.